# grep specific number from lines 5 but not 25 or 52 and so on

Tags: text-processing

I need to find a user for a userid. The return from the authentication system is as follows. Now with a bash script I need to extract the line with the exact number. Not 5 and 25 ..

```
------------
ID  LOGIN   
------------
28  user1
25  user2 
5   user3
```

If I use `grep 5` I do get 2 lines but I need the line with "5".

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways of doing it.

IMHO the best way is to use `awk`, which is useful when dealing with fields.

If you want a `grep` based solution, I would do:

```
grep -w '^5'
```

The `-w` tells `grep` to match the exact word, so this will not match "52". The "^" tells grep to search the 5 at the beginning of the line, which will fail if there are e.g. leading spaces.

The `awk` solution would look like:

```
awk '$1 == 5'
```

If you want only the username, which is the second column:

```
awk '$1 == 5 {print $2}'
```

If you're searching for a string and not a numeric value, enclose the string in double quotes:

```
awk '$1 == "abc" {print $2}'
```

Comment: thanks I have choosen the awk way. awk '$1 == 5 {print $2}' that worked.

Comment: @Dave. Since this answer worked for you, please consider clicking the checkbox beside it to signal to future readers it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with a regex (first char in line) and including the space:

```
grep -E "^5 "
```

Comment: This would be better as `grep -E "^5\s"` in case there's a tab and not a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
query-auth-system | grep "^5\\>"
```

- `^`: means "match at start of line
- `\\>`: matches a word-boundary. So it will match `5`, but not `50`.

Comment: That will also match lines starting with `5:`, `5%`, `5|` etc.